# Detecting whether a snowball in minecraft is broken after its been thrown

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I was wondering if it was possible to detect whether a snowball has broken after it has been thrown by the user.

Answer (score 1):

A simple answer is by Dragnoz's [contraption](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7dCldR5bpOo) he made. This is making deadly snowballs but it still shows you a way of tracking the snowball.

The simple way to track it is as follows:

`/scoreboard players add @e[type=Snowball] Ball 1` where `Ball` is a new dummy object.

And then an easy way you can do it is hook the command block up to a comparator and when it doesn't give a signal, you reverse it with a redstone torch and activate your command. Depending on your knowledge, the other way might be far to complicated for you, no offense.